# How can I put code snippet here with proper new line placement?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Hello,
I am wondering if it is possible to put in here code with proper new line placement (by proper I mean - where I want ) because if I put for instance a new line in a code snippet marked with `` then it breaks the code block and gets unformatted :/